how to set a cookie in a flask project?
i want to set a cookie in my flask project, I don't want to use the way below, I just want a cookie to be set for the user when he enters a route.
res = make_response('...')
res.set_cookie("login", value=password)

I tried this way but it didn't work
res = make_response()
res.set_cookie("login", value=password)


As a sidenote: setting the password as a cookie is not a good plan.

I know this, but this is for a specific project

If I am understanding this correctly, you can just do this:
@app.route('/')
def index():
    # Set the cookie
    response = make_response('')
    response.set_cookie('login', 'password')
    return response

This way, the default behavior when the user accesses the route '/' will be to set this cookie
More information here: https://pythonbasics.org/flask-cookies/
